# Find each customer's second order date in a list of all orders

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of all orders placed in a time range and I am trying to calculate the difference between each customer's first and second order. I have a list of unique customer IDs on another tab and I already have the first order date for each. I need a way to grab the date of the second order, corresponding to each customer ID.

In the sample data below, the correct output of this formula for customer ID "153950" would be "5/11/17 8:41".

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE()

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,Sheet1!C1:C4/(Sheet1!A1:A4 = 153950),2)
```

The `,2` is grabbing the second smallest date.

Comment: Works like a charm. I have never used AGGREGATE before. Thanks1

Comment: @TedGlasnow please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  and next time be aware of the [XYProblem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  ask how to get the end answer and not the step that you think will get you there.

Comment: Hey, @ScottCranner. If I wanted to find the date of the 3rd order, would I just replace the 2 with a 3?

Comment: @TedGlasnow yes.  It will error though if there is not a third.

Comment: ....@ScottCranner one more tag to my original question. Would it be possible to filter out orders where the value in the "Order Total" column is 0?

Comment: Yes but I am away from the computer. Ask a new question and link back to this one. Some one will get an answer to you quicker than I can.