# Filter out all orders of $0 with AGGREGATE function

Tags: excel-formula

I was able to find an answer to the question linked below, but now I am interested in adding one more tweak.

I had a list of all orders placed in a time range and was am trying to calculate the difference between each customer's first and second order. I had a list of unique customer IDs on another tab and the first order date for each. I was able to find the difference between first and second order date with the and AGGREGATE formula, but now I would like to also filter out all orders where the "Order Total" is 0.

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,Sheet1!C1:C4/(Sheet1!A1:A4 = 153950),2)
```

Original Question:

[Find each customer's second order date in a list of all orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714059/find-each-customers-second-order-date-in-a-list-of-all-orders)

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, Sheet1!C1:C4/((Sheet1!A1:A4=153950)*(Sheet1!B1:B4<>0)), 2)
```

The idea here is that you want to create a simple maths formula that will #DIV/0! on anything you don't want while AGGREGATE ignores errors thus discarding those from consideration. False (for all intents and purposes) is zero and anything multiplied by zero is zero; anything divided by zero is #DIV/0!. Any number divided by 1 (e.g. true x true) remains unchanged.