# Find values through index, but safe from deletion

Tags: excel, excel-formula, delete-row, excel-2016

I've got a input sheet that contains several different variables among which names, location and job. I want to display these values on different sheet, in which I summarize the data by group. So the input is as follows

```
    A        B     C
1   NAME     CIYY  WORK
2   Bart     NY    Plumber
3   Emily    NY    Firefighter
4   Daniel   LA    Firefighter
5   Cohen    NY    Firefighter
6   Sasha    LA    Plumber
7   Dirk     LA    Plumber
8   Molly    LA    Plumber
```

Now I want to find the names from plumbers in LA, meaning it needs to look like this: (no `#NA` and no empty cells in between)

```
    A     
1   NAME
2   Sasha 
3   Dirk  
4   Molly
```

Should be easy with Indexing, Matching etc. However, the input is changed by simply deleting rows and adding rows. **How can I achieve this without the risk of** `#REF` **errors**. When Dirk would be deleted for instance, the output should look as follows:

```
    A     
1   NAME
2   Sasha 
4   Molly
```

[The solution on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497062/filter-an-array-using-a-formula-without-vba) comes pretty close but leaves me with a `#NA` when the conditions are not met. 
Although the values will be unique, I have a feeling that [this solution for extracting unique values](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-unique-items-from-a-list) will be helpfull, but have been unable to combine them.

Comment: You have no column geader label. You require a top row that will never be deleted or you risk #REF! errors.

Comment: \*column *header* label

Comment: Thanks for notifying. I added the column header labels in the examples. They are present in the actual file, but that didn't bring me closer to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a two column match using INDEX and AGGREGATE.

```
=INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("zzz", A:A)))/((B$1:INDEX(B:B, MATCH("zzz", A:A))=G$2)*(C$1:INDEX(C:C, MATCH("zzz", A:A))=H$2)), ROW(1:1)))
```

Fill down for successive matches. Use an IFERROR wrapper if you do not want error codes once you have run out of matches.

[image]

Comment: Awesome. That works like a charme. I also figured something out using INDIRECT and additional subvariables but this one is much better! Thanks! I'll post my solution soon for completeness sake.

Comment: By the way, could you perhaps also explain what the Aggregate function does? I am trying to disect it but it is a rather lengthy one

Comment: See explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910564/filter-out-all-orders-of-0-with-aggregate-function/48910918#48910918).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, giving the whole range, cells and columns:

```
=INDEX(1:1048576,MATCH("Bart",A:A,0),MATCH("NY",2:2,0))
```

Thus, you can delete from `A:A` and from `2:2`, the ranges would stay untouched.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this issue by using INDRECT. I do not like this function however and would still advise to use the solution proposed by Jeeped.

The solution requires three steps.

1. Add an extra column with the two strings combined: i.e. `D2 = B2&C2`, and store the row of the first occurence of LAPlumber with `=MATCH($M$17;D:D;0)`
2. Now, iteratively, find the row of the next occurence of LAPlumber with:  `=IFERROR(MATCH($M$17;INDIRECT("$D$"&SUM($N$17:$N17;1)&":$D$16";TRUE);0);"")`. This function uses the previous row-numbers to redefine the array with INDIRECT. **Note, the results of these values are relative to the previous row.**
3. For each row, find the corresponding name: `=INDEX($A$1:$C$15;SUM($N$17:N18);O$16)`. The sum function is used to combine the relative row-numbers.

In the picture I added a screenshot of step 3. Cell H3 contains step 1. The other cells in column `H` show the row numbers from step 2. 
[image]